# How to display control message info on omnet++?

Tags: routes, protocols, omnet++

How to display control message info on scalars omnet++?

when I run the DSDV network, I don't find the control message info. How to display the control message

Comment: What exactly do you want to display? Number of received messages? Number of sent messages?